# How to transform data with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am really new to XSLT but I was wondering if I could use it to solve a problem.
I would like to transform data like this:
 
 
<thing id=1>
 
    <value>T</value>
 
    <dateTime>1/11/2011 09:30 PM</dateTime>
 
</thing>
 
 
<thing id=1>
    <value>F</value>
 
    <dateTime>1/11/2011 09:32 PM</dateTime>
 
</thing>
 
 
<thing id=2>
    <value>T</value>
    <dateTime>1/11/2011 09:35 PM</dateTime>
</thing>
<thing id=1>
    <value>T</value>
    <dateTime>1/11/2011 09:37 PM</dateTime>
</thing>
<thing id=2>
    <value>F</value>
    <dateTime>1/11/2011 09:40 PM</dateTime>
</thing>
<thing id=1>
    <value>F</value>
    <dateTime>1/11/2011 09:45 PM</dateTime>
</thing>

Into a table like this:
Thing 1
T                                      F                                     Duration
1/11/2011 09:30 PM        1/11/2011 09:32 PM        02:00
1/11/2011 09:37 PM        1/11/2011 09:45 PM        08:00
Thing 2
T                                      F                                     Duration
1/11/2011 09:35 PM        1/11/2011 09:40 PM        05:00

Also, in my above example, I am presuming I have matching (i.e paired) T and F values. If one were actually missing, I would want it to display null or nothing.

So, with that in mind, is it possible to use xslt? If so, how would I do it?

Thanks,

John

Comment: For the most part it is possible to do what you want, use XSLT to convert valid XML such as you've outlined into a textfile containing sections for each thing:id.  One tricky aspect is handling the missing values.  It is probably easier to catch the T's without matching F's (starts without finishes) and ignore the F's without T's, if any. Would that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot ignore the missing F's. I would need to capture this information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether to use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 here. Your problem involves grouping, and grouping is much easier in XSLT 2.0 - but not all environments yet support XSLT 2.0.

I don't think it's worth trying to suggest any code until you have made this decision.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If it is easier to do in XSLT 2.0 then I would use it.